db2 procedure inconsistent?
currently facing a very strange problem. when i try the following, i get some rows returned, as expected:
call "clm".MY_PROCEDURE('M00894761','','M_OM','BP_00000858_OM','0','SEARCH_BENUTILACC_WOMDP')

but when i run my procedure with slightly different parameters:
call "clm".MY_PROCEDURE('M00628255','','M_OM','BP_00002816_OM','0','SEARCH_BENUTILACC_WOMDP')

the following message is returned:
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "OM S1 UNION SELECT *".  
Expected tokens may include:  "<table_expr>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.31.10

why does the first query work, but the second one doesnt? both queries are being ran from two different dbs, but the contents of the procedures are exactly the same

Insufficient information. Possible causes: (1) things are different from your assumptions  (2) the procedure code is defective (3) There are other differences in the running environment(versions/fixpacks/vrm/settings/configs) that are relevant.   You need to do some problem determination at your site to localise the problem. But if you see the code-fragment (shown in message) in procedure source-code, time to carefully review...

@mao it was caused by white space. for whatever reason, one of my dbs cannot handle white space very well, but once i removed them between the sql statements, it worked

Delete this question, so that others do not have to read it.
